# Load balance client connections across network of ActiveMQ brokers

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I have setup network of brokers in ActiveMQ with two nodes. Everything works fine except that all the clients connected to one broker and the second broker doesn't have any connections. I have enabled `updateClusterClients` and `rebalanceClusterClients`. I thought enabling these options will allow clients to re-balance themselves.

### Environment detail

1. Python 3.7
2. Stomp protocol
3. ActiveMQ 5.15.8
4. using stomp+ssl transport connector

### Sample code with failover transport:

```py
conn = stomp.Connection11([(localhost,61613),(remotehost,61613)], heartbeats= 
       (10000,20000),encoding="utf-8",heart_beat_receive_scale=2.0)
conn.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `updateClusterClients` and `rebalanceClusterClients` settings only apply to OpenWire clients. STOMP is a very simple protocol (as the name suggests). There is no standard way for the broker to inform a STOMP client about cluster topology updates or to tell it to connect to a different broker. It's just not part of the specification. You'll need to balance your clients manually or perhaps use an external load-balancer.